# returning a value based on a dynamic position in a table (OFFSET?)

Tags: excel, match, offset

I have a large table filled with scores, visually separated by empty rows and an employee name at the start (A2, for instance).  On another worksheet (same book), I'd like to return the averages that exist at the end of the rows of data for the employee.  The catch is that the employee names will come from a Data Validation list and could change based on user selection.  All averages need to correspond to the selected employee.  The relative position between employee name and requested value will be fixed, so I thought of OFFSET, but so far, no joy.

Range A1:H8 on image is one set of data.  Range A9:H16 is another set (there will be 30+ sets total).  Column H holds the Average data that is needed.  A26 is the variable that can be changed to pull up a specific employees data, and B26:F26 are the averages that come from column H.  A25:F26 will be on another sheet, just put them on the same for the picture to follow: [Sample data set for question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPUsw.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a formula like this to locate the required block of data (xmatch) then find the averages for each system (xlookup on the system name) if you have Excel 365:

```
=LET(range,$A$1:$H$20,
blocksize,7,
startrow,XMATCH($A26,INDEX(range,0,2)),
endcol,COLUMNS(range),
dataset,INDEX(range,startrow,1):INDEX(range,startrow+blocksize-1,endcol),
XLOOKUP(B25,INDEX(dataset,0,1),INDEX(dataset,0,endcol)))
```

[image]

You can also do it as a spill formula:

```
=LET(range,A1:H20,
blocksize,7,
startrow,XMATCH(A26,INDEX(range,0,2)),
endcol,COLUMNS(range),
dataset,INDEX(range,startrow,1):INDEX(range,startrow+blocksize-1,endcol),
XLOOKUP(B25:F25,INDEX(dataset,0,1),INDEX(dataset,0,endcol)))
```

You could also do it the same way without Excel 365 using ordinary match and vlookup:

```
=VLOOKUP(B25,INDEX($A$1:H$20,MATCH($A26,$B$1:$B$20,0),1):INDEX($A$1:H$20,MATCH($A26,$B$1:$B$20,0)+6,8),8,FALSE)
```

Comment: Heading in to work now, I will give this a shot.  I think I follow some of the formula but since I'm not familiar with half of Excel's functions, I'll need to see it in action to understand more.  I'll post when I've tried it out, thank you!

Comment: Moved my work over to 365 and had to make an adjustment to the data range, but I'm getting an error.  Including screenshot because your knowledge outstrips mine and I can't see what is wrong with it.  Oops, not able to add screenshot, so I'll include the formula.
=LET(range,$A$1:$AY$22,
blocksize,7,
startrow,XMATCH($A26,INDEX(range,0,2)),
endcol,COLUMNS(range),
dataset,INDEX(range,startrow,1):INDEX(range,startrow+blocksize-1,endcol),
XLOOKUP(B25,INDEX(dataset,0,1),INDEX(dataset,0,endcol))

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - I left a bracket off the end of the first formula when I pasted it into the answer, but it's correct on the screenshot.